# Deleting linked list in c- crash

Tags: c, list, linked-list, crash

I'm trying to delete a list of PItem. This is the declaration of PItem

```
typedef struct Item{
    int num;
    float price;
    struct Item* next;
}*PItem;
```

This is the function where I try to delete the list

```
void deleteList(PItem* ptr, PItem *tail){
    PItem *temp;
    while ((*ptr)->next){
        temp = ptr;
        *ptr = (*ptr)->next;
        free(*temp);
    }
    tail = NULL;
}
```

The weird part is that it crashes only on the second run of the loop, before the

```
free(*temp);
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In debug mode have you guaranteed that the head doesnt loose its reference? Does it give you any errors? if yes post it/them. or it just crahshes on you instantly?

Comment: crashes instantly- no errors

Comment: Never happened that to me while programming.
I dont know of any error that would instantly crash VS
Did you try to check the logs for troubleshooting?

Comment: no... it doesn't crash the actual VS, it crashes the c program

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using more indirection than you need. The `temp` variable should be a pointer, not a pointer to pointer. Here is what happens when you do this:

```
// Temp points to the same pointer as ptr, so
temp = ptr;
// when the value pointed to by ptr changes, so does the value pointed to by temp
*ptr = (*ptr)->next;
// When you free *temp, you also free *ptr
free(*temp);
```

Fixing this problem is simple: declare `temp` as `PItem`, and use it to make copies of `ptr`:

```
PItem temp;
while (*ptr) { // Loop should proceed till *ptr is NULL, not (*ptr)->next
    temp = *ptr; // Copy the pointer's value
    *ptr = temp->next; // Advance *ptr
    free(temp); // Delete temp, which points to the old *ptr
}
// tail is a pointer to a pointer, so you should add * to the assignment
*tail = NULL;
```